# I'm unable to republish/overwrite an existing dataset in my shared workspace nor can I refresh it

Tags: powerbi, refresh

I haven't done any changes in my dataset for a while and in the past few days, the refresh and publish features (via PBI Desktop) were working just fine. However, this morning, it suddenly stopped following through the scheduled/automatic refresh which were set 5x a day every 2 hours starting 8AM. When Itrigger manual refresh, it says "Preparing for refresh" but doesn't really follow through with it, so i kept on clicking it but to no avail. After a while, I checked the Refresh History and the error I got was it's timing out.

I was trying to republish it with a newer version which was the same dataset refreshed in a different workspace. Apparently, when I publish it to a different workspace, or if I rename it and publish it to my existing shared workspace, it works. BUT I don't want to push through with this kind of workaround because I cannot afford to redo my the set up of RLS and manage permission in the dataset of my existing workspace.

Hope you can help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try signing in to the workspace using a browser, then use the Get Data feature (arrow button at bottom left), then choose Files / Local File and select your PBIX.

It's effectively the same results as a Publish from Power BI Desktop, but sometimes the method above works when Power BI Desktop is jammed up.

You might also have a refresh issue, not a publish issue.  There's an unannounced-refresh-on-publish feature that most people don't notice:

"When you republish a dataset published from Power BI Desktop and have a refresh schedule defined, a dataset refresh is started as soon as you republish."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-upload-desktop-files